# Call a python method if an item in context menu is clicked

Tags: python, windows, right-click

I have a "running" python application and I want it to perform an action on a file when q user right clicks the file and chooses a context menu item. For example, if the user right clicks and chooses "Do something", I want to call the following function in my python code: "do_something_on(file_path)".

A half-baked solution that I have in mind is to run the code as a service and let it listen for events. Then on right click, I would run a small script that would send a message to the listener. Is there an approach that lets me call the function directly? Without going to the trouble of creating a service, etc?

Comment: What application is that? A web application? Or do you use PyQt or tkinter?

Comment: It is a desktop application that runs is background (the application is in one big thread). It also has an optional wxPython gui.